# 3d printing a part from Blender

Tags: modeling, objects, export, 3d-printing, append

PROBLEM SOLVED...THANKS PGMATH FOR THE HELP.

I'm brand new to using Blender, and I'm trying to teach myself some basics to use in conjunction with 3D printing.  To do that I'm trying to 3D print a plate with a logo on it.  However, I'm having an issue with one single letter in the logo showing up as "negative" space after slicing the model in the 3D print software (Repetier-Host).

I'm lost on why this is happening or where in the process I'm messing up?  The only thing I notice that is strange is that the shadowing for the letter in Blender looks a little different from the surrounding parts (and its more noticeable when input into the print software). In Blender and Repetier-Host that specific letter still looks extruded, even though the shadowing is strange (less shadowing, i guess), and its not until the model gets sliced does it become "negative".

And it's not like each letter in the logo was uploaded separately.  The entire logo was a single PNG file originally and converted to a SVG file through Inkscape. So why this specific letter is behaving differently is very confusing?

And FYI...when making the file Blender file I appended the logo (previously extruded) with a plate part to create the file full part.

Anybody have any thoughts or experiences with something like this?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you upload a .blend file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part about the shading looking slightly different sounds like the normals are flipped.  To flip a face's normal, select the face(s) in edit mode and hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd>, then select *flip normals*.

[Here is the documentation](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Editing/Faces) on normals, at the bottom of the page.

Comment: PGmath...that appears to be what the problem was.  I took your suggestion and made the change to that specific letter, and it looks great now.  Thanks so much for the help.  Not sure why that one letter had a backwards normal like that, but I'll definitely be more aware of that possibility in future.

Comment: @Polosson where did you get the button characters you added to my answer?

Comment: you just have to add the <kbd></kbd> tags around it. Click the "Edit" button to see what I mean.

Comment: Note that you can also flip the normals with Ctrl+Shift+N